# Got an error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in jquery.dataTables.min.js

Tags: jquery

I dont understand what this means and how to fix this?
I am running in chrome with firebug lite

under the reasources tab jquery.dataTables.min.js has a 1 next to it stating the error

any help please?

Comment: It means it can't find the resource. The path to the file is most likely incorrect.

Comment: meaning to the file jquery.dataTables.min.js? oo ok yikes.. I will search my code and find where it want to access this file ans check the path...thanks